# How to get a certain object from an interface arraylist

Tags: java

Hey guys im stuck on a problem.
Say I have an interface Animal.  I then have classes that implement it such as Dog, Cat, Goat. say each of these classes has an update()  function that they get from the interface.

I have an arraylist of Animal,that includes all different kinds of the animal classes (dog, cat, goat).  If i was given a string that says "Goat" how would i search that arraylist and choose only the Goat update() function, ignoring Dog and Cat...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for ( Animal a : animals ) {
    if ( a instanceof Goat ) {
       a.update();
    }
}
```

If you really only have the String "Goat" to go on you could do something like this:

```
if ( a.getClass().getName().endsWith("Goat") ) {
    //...
```

Or if the String has nothing to do with the name of the class, you could map a String to an instance of Class:

```
Map<String, Class<? extends Animal>> map = new HashMap...
map.put("Goat", Goat.class);

//...
if ( map.get("Goat").isInstance(a) ) {
   a.update();
}
```

In my opinion [Google's Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29) is the best choice:

```
 for ( Goat g : Iterables.filter(animals, Goat.class) ) {
    g.update();
 }
```

Comment: yes i only have the string to go by, so the second option did the trick

Comment: @Jonathan: you might want to be careful with that, as this would also update all `PrairieDog`s if you passed in `"Dog"`, for example.  A better way would be to use `a.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Goat")`  However, in both cases you won't be matching subclasses of Goat, only objects which are exactly `Goat`.  The third option is more stable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void goatUpdate(List<Animal> animals) {
    for (Animal animal : animals) {
        if (animal instanceof Goat) {
            animal.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you will need to go through the list asking for the type of each object. If you have `List<Animal>` there is (as far as I know) no easy one-line way to get only specfied subclass of it.